# Cannot login into gerrit interface with github openid

Tags: github, openid, gerrit

I have setup a gerrit server and want to use **github.com** for openID authentication.

But, I couldn't login. If I entrr the url as https://github.com/openid or http://github.com/openid,

I a getting the error "Provider is not supported, or was incorrectly entered.'

Following is my gerrit.config

```
[gerrit]
        basePath = git
        canonicalWebUrl = http://localhost:7070/
[database]
        type = h2
        database = db/ReviewDB
[auth]
        type = OpenID
        trustedOpenID = https://github.com/openid
[sendemail]
        enable = false
        smtpServer = localhost
[container]
        user = root
        javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
[sshd]
        listenAddress = *:29412
[httpd]
        listenUrl = http://*:7070/
[cache]
        directory = cache
```

What do I miss? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

GitHub is unfortunatly not a OpenID authentication provider. https://github.com/openid is not an OpenID authentication URL, but actually the GitHub account of the [OpenID Foundation](http://openid.net/).